# Error with DateTime::__construct() and date.timezone

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, timezone

When I run te following command line in my server:

`$ php -r '$d = new \DateTime("2017-05-22");'`

It works great.

On other hand, I have an symfony web application in the same server with below method:

```
function createAdFromFeedAction(Request $request){
    try{
        $ad_values = $request->request->all();
        $datetime = new \DateTime($ad_values["date"]);
    }
    catch(\Exception $e ){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

But I get the exception message:

> DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system\'s
>   timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting
>   or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of
>   those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone \'UTC\'
>   for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.null

I have setted the `date.timezone` in `php.ini` file as you can see:
[image]

I have restart the web server and clean symfony cache doing: `php app/console cache:clear --env=dev`

What am I doing wrong?

**Note**: In production server works fine so I won't use `date_default_timezone_set()`.

**Note2**: That is my timezone from phpinfo():
[image]

**Note3** php version's dev server is PHP 5.4.45-1~dotdeb+7.1 (cli) and php version's prod is PHP 5.4.36-0+deb7u1 (cli)

Comment: This  might sound a little bit silly, but can you check phpinfo() if date.timezone is truly set.

Comment: can you access you production server, see the settings of php.ini in your production and compare.

Comment: @invisal sure, see **Note2**

Comment: @webDev `date.timezone` is empty in `php.ini` in production server

Comment: oh ok, so on your production, the configuration depends on the php config not on php.ini. Woudl you please access config file on production and set your time zone accordingly. Access your settings file and set there, put blank on php.ini. and also check your local dev server config. server config matters if php.ini not set. so compare your server time zone and symfony settings.

Comment: and this is not the error this just the warning msg i think. so you can hide this exception by putting @ in front of the date method `\@DateTIme(....)`. or hide notice, warnings etc on your local server using php.ini.

Comment: @webDev Where do I find php config?msg seems to be a warning but note that it is catching the exception. `\@DateTIme(....)` throws a syntax error exception.

Comment: `settings.yml` is the symfony's php config file for time zone. did you try with `@\DateTIme....` The symfony way is to use default_timezone in `settings.yml`. http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/04-Settings#chapter_04_sub_default_timezone